# R %in% doesn't work for values greater than -0.999

Tags: r

Today I came across an oddity with base I can't find an explanation for.

I have an interval (-0.031,0.105) and I wanted to test if 0 (zero) was in this.  Simple, but...

```
> 0 %in% -0.031:0.105
[1] FALSE
```

A quick play shows that R can happily do this for values less than -1 though.

```
> 0 %in% -1.0:0.105
[1] TRUE
```

Can anyone shed light on why this doesn't work as expected and how to resolve?

Comment: `:` doesn't do what you think it does. Look at the output of `-0.031:0.105` and `-1.0:0.105` and read the documentation in `help(":")`. Package data.table defines the `%between%` operator for what you actually need, but you can easily use `<=`, `>=`, and `&`.

Comment: Ah... thanks for the heads up.  So R when creating vectors as shown (with :) isn't doing what I wanted.  Simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The %in% operator**

The `%in%` operator looks for a value in a vector and returns `TRUE` if he found the value (at least once). Some examples:

```
0 %in% c(-1,0,1)
> TRUE # zero is in the vector
0 %in% c(-0.5,0.5)
> FALSE # zero is not in the vector
'Anna' %in% c('Anna','Bob')
> TRUE # it also works for characters
```

**The : operator**

The `:` operator is short for `seq(from,to)`. One of the default values of `seq()` is the step which is 1 by default. Therefore this would be the output of your code:

```
-0.031:0.105
> [1] -0.031 # (to is less than 1 higher than from)
-1.0:0.105
> [1] -1  0 # (here he can actually add a second number which is the 0)
```

As you can see this is not exactly the behavior that you want to achieve. There is however a function that does this:

**The between function**

Bot dplyr and data.table provide functions to create this behavior:
`dplyr::between(value, lower, upper)` or `data.table::between(value, lower, upper)`. The data.table `%between%` operator is based upon the `data.table::between()` function. Therefore, in your case you could do:

```
between(0,-0.031,0.105)
> TRUE
```

which would correctly return `TRUE`.